# How to disable message, call, mail options from contact List using Address Book Api?

Tags: swift, ios11, addressbook

Is it possible to disable message, call, mail etc options from contact List using Address Book Api

I just want user can select only address from contact list.

**For reference please check below marked option on image.**

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about within the Contacts app? Or are you talking about some contact you're showing via the AddressBookUI or ContactsUI within your own app?

Comment: I am using AddressBook within my application for importing Address from contact list. I need to disable other options then Address.

Comment: @Rob - I am using ContactsUI

Comment: we have to display them in disabled mode that is the requirement.

Comment: did you already found any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is CNContact property keys to display in the contact detail card. You can do this by setting displayedPropertyKeys property of CNContactPickerViewController when you showing the contact list:

```
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPostalAddressesKey]
```

If you are showing the contact using CNContactViewController then can disable action using allowsActions property:

```
    let controller = CNContactViewController(for: SELECTED_CONTACT)
    controller.contactStore = CNContactStore()
    controller.allowsActions = false
    controller.delegate = self
```

**Complete implemention:**

Function for showing CNContactPickerViewController:

```
@IBAction func showContactList( sender: Any) ->Void{
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Implement delegate for CNContactPickerViewController:

```
public func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact){
    print(#function)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:{
        self.showDetailFor(contact: contact)
    })
}
```

to display details of contact open CNContactViewController:

```
func showDetailFor(contact: CNContact) -> Void{
    let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: contact)
    contactViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
    contactViewController.delegate = self
    contactViewController.allowsActions = false
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
}
```

implement CNContactViewControllerDelegate to get selected property or handle action for any property:

```
func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController,
                           shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool{
// return true if want to perform any action on selected property otherwise return false
    return false
}
```

Comment: That is I am already using. I have to disable message, call, mail options which are marked on image.

Comment: Those buttons are still visible and enabled when you do this.

Comment: @Rob - You are Right, Is there any way to disable those buttons?

Comment: @PremaJanoti - did you check with edited answer for selected contact?

Comment: @Rocky - Yes I checked your edited answer, But I am using CNContactPickerViewController not CNContactViewController.

Comment: @PremaJanoti - You could implement `didSelect` of the contact (preventing it from showing the `CNContactViewController` itself) and then do the above inside that `didSelect` method, thereby disabling the actions.

Comment: @Rocky - I think you're on the right track here. I wonder about `didSelect`, though, because in my tests, with `didSelect`, it's automatically dismissed (in fact, I really dislike that behavior), so I'm not sure you want to dismiss it twice. I just `DispatchQueue.main.async { showDetail(for: ...) }`.

Comment: @Rocky - Thanks for your efforts I really appreciate it, But it is not as per my requirement. I think it is not possible to disable those buttons (message, call, video and mail) in contract detail.